# How to get a clojure handle on a Java static method, similar to _memfn_ for a Java instance method?

Tags: clojure

To get a handle on a Java instance method which we can invoke later on, we can call the *memfn* function:

```
user=> (def g (memfn Integer/toString))
#'user/g

user=> (g 789)
"789"
```

This doesn't work for Java static methods:

```
user=> (def g (memfn Integer/toHexString))
#'user/g

user=> (g 789)
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: toHexString for class java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:52)

user=> (g)
ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: user$g  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

How can we get a handle to a Java static method, so we can invoke it later on?

Comment: The anonymous function literal, `#(.foo ...)`, is generally preferred over memfn, so too would it be for static methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(defn g [x] (Integer/toHexString x))`...? If you want, you can wrap that up in a macro, but there's not much left to do:

```
(defmacro static-fn [f] `(fn [x#] (~f x#)))
(def g (static-fn Integer/toHexString))
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a nudge towards the much harder problem I had which required two levels of back-quoting and escaping.